# Check if value of the current matched element is empty or null or undefined and set boolVar to true

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've this HTML table and I need to find whether `.has_paises` has or not text. For example in the code below, for the first `tr` condition will be true since `$(".has_paises").text()` should return *Some text* but for the second `tr` condition will be false since the same code will return empty or null or undefined or whatever `.text()` return.

```
<table id="contenedorFabricantes" style="" class="table table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr class="tableHead">
            <th><input type="checkbox" name="toggleCheckboxFabricantes" id="toggleCheckboxFabricantes"></th>
            <th>Fabricante</th>
            <th>Dirección</th>
            <th>País</th>
            <th>Teléfono</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="fabricanteBody">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" value="1"></td><td>Dist1</td>
            <td>Direccion</td>
            <td class="has_pais" id="td-1">Some text</td>
            <td>999999</td>
            <td><a data-backdrop="static" data-target="#addPaisesFabricante" data-toggle="modal" id="1" class="editable-pais" href="#"><i title="" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" class="fa fa-plus-circle" data-original-title="Agregar países"></i></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" value="1"></td><td>Dist2</td>
            <td>Direccion</td>
            <td class="has_pais" id="td-2"></td>
            <td>999999</td>
            <td><a data-backdrop="static" data-target="#addPaisesFabricante" data-toggle="modal" id="2" class="editable-pais" href="#"><i title="" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" class="fa fa-plus-circle" data-original-title="Agregar países"></i></a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to iterate all over `tr` in `#fabricanteBody` and find if at least one of the matched elements is **empty** or **null** or **undefined** and if this is true then set boolVar to true so I'll check later on my code if that var is true or false, so I think to do it in this way:

```
var hasFab = $("#fabricanteBody").find(".has_pais"),
    boolVar = false;

hasFab.forEach(function(value, index, array){
   // check goes here and set boolVar goes here
});
```

Since, though, value is not a jQuery object but Javascript how do I check if value of the current matched element is empty or null or undefined and set `boolVar` to true? Also if at least one `.has_paises` is empty don't need to check the rest of them just set `boolVar` to true and continue code execution, meaning get out from `forEach` cycle. Any help? Suggestions are accepted for improve my code, I made it on my mind and is not perfect I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter by text and check if the collection has length, if so it contains elements without text

```
var boolVar = $("#fabricanteBody").find(".has_pais").filter(function() {
                  return $.trim( $(this).text() ).length > 0;
              }).length > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var boolVar = !$('#fabricanteBody .has_pais:empty').length;
```

[See documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

This uses `.get()` to let jQuery return a real array, and `.some()` to iterate over it. `.some()` stops iteration when the callback returns true. The callback gets the DOM-elements content and returns true if it is null, undefined or an empty string.

```
var boolVar = $("#fabricanteBody .has_pais").get().some(function(el) {
    var content = el.innerHTML; return !content && content !== 0;
});
```

[Array.prototype.some reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).